# stdoutt and stderr redirection using tee in shell script

Tags: function, unix, stdout, io-redirection, tee

I'm trying to print output/error to console and log file using below code.

fun1(){

echo "inside fun1"

fun2

var=5

}

fun2(){

echo "inside fun2"

}

fun1 2>&1 | tee -a testlog.txt

echo $var   # printing null value

Any way to print value of var as 5 after fun1 execution?? I need output in both console and log file. Also fun1 should be executed only once.

please help.

Comment: You ask a couple of (independent) questions in one. Consider posting a number of separate questions.

Comment: My only concern is to display the value of $var

Answer (score 1):

If you write it as a bash script it is possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1 1> >(tee testlog.txt) 2>&1

fun1(){
    echo 'inside fun1'
    fun2
    var=5
}

fun2(){
    echo 'inside fun2'
}

fun1
echo "$var"
```

If you rather want to do it as a normal bourn shell, you could separate it into two scripts:

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

fun1(){
    echo 'inside fun1'
    fun2
    var=5
}

fun2(){
    echo 'inside fun2'
}

fun1
echo $var
```

and script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

script2.sh 2>&1 | tee testlog.txt
```